# How do you pass "Program Files" to PsExec?

Tags: powershell, psexec

I've already read and tried various ways, but it just won't take it

Here is my script :

```
$computers=Get-Content -Path "C:\tmp\computers.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers){

psexec64.exe \\$computer -h -u admin -p passW0rd cmd /c "C:\Program Files\uninstall\uninstall.bat --force"


}
```

Output :

```
psexec64.exe : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:7 char:1
+ psexec64.exe \\$computer -h -u admin -p passW0rd cmd /c "C:\Prog ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('C:\Program' is...ternal command,:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
operable program or batch file.
Connecting to 192.168.110.11...Starting PSEXESVC service on 192.168.110.11...Connecting with PsExec service on 192.168.110.11...Starting cmd on 
192.168.110.11...
cmd exited on 192.168.110.11 with error code 1.
```

Comment: Try: psexec64.exe \\$computer -h -u admin -p passW0rd cmd /c "'C:\Program Files\uninstall\uninstall.bat' --force"

Comment: Try using the call operator,   ampersand.  See get-help about_operators.

Comment: You can also use the [Stop-parsing token (`--%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-5.1#stop-parsing-token---): `psexec64.exe \\$computer -h -u admin -p passW0rd cmd /c --% "C:\Program Files\uninstall\uninstall.bat --force"`

Comment: You can see some help about the call operator [here](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)